# How to replace values from one dataset, with values from another dataset in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm looking to replace rows in my dataframe with values from another one in R. I have merged the two together and created a column which specifies what dataframe the data has come from (data_set). Where the same 'project_element' appears in both data sets, I want to replace it with it's corresponding value from the other dataset. E.g. below is an extract of the data frame I have. I would like to replace the 'Task 1' value from the data_set pets, with the value from the animals data_set.

```
df1<-data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                project_element = c("Task 1", "Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3", "Task 4"), 
                data_set = c("pets", "animals", "pets", "pets", "pets"))
```

Would someone be able to advise me on how to do this, or recommend a good resource for looking this up?

Many thanks.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. You should not change your question so much after others put in the effort to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

For each project you could reverse the values so that values for dataset 'pets' go to 'animals' and vice-versa.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(project_element) %>% mutate(new_value = rev(value))

#  value project_element data_set new_value
#  <dbl> <chr>           <chr>        <dbl>
#1     1 Task 1          pets             2
#2     2 Task 1          animals          1
#3     3 Task 2          pets             3
#4     4 Task 3          pets             4
#5     5 Task 4          pets             5
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
df1$new_value <- with(df1, ave(value, project_element, FUN = rev))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
setDT(df)
df[, index := 1:.N, by = "project_element"]
df <- data.frame(df) %>%
  group_by(project_element) %>%
  mutate(
    value = ifelse(value != df[df$data_set == "animals",]$value & sum(index) > 2, df[df$data_set == "animals",]$value, value)
  )
```

It creates an index that counts the number of occurences of the same `project_element`, and use the sum of the index columns for deciding which rows must be replaced.